# Can "ContentResolver's call method" be called on the UI thread?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I wanted to make sure whether the "call" method of ContentResolver can be called on the UI thread. I've tried google but nothing was found. Can anyone help with this? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by call method?

Comment: @blackapps the "call " method/function in ContentResolver.java

Comment: ????? Well give an example in your post i would say.

Comment: @blackapps   ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver().call(uri, "methodName", null, bundle)

Comment: @blackapps No, I just wanted to know if I can call this method on the UI thread. Is it a proper way to call it on the UI thread?

Comment: My god. Why didn't you try? Try! And then tell us. What is your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235253/discussion-between-leon-and-blackapps).